# Mule condense data based on a category

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Example below. I've got a set of account numbers, with an account attribute. For each account_number there are three categories, and I would like the sum for each account number based on each balance in DataWeave.

Data input

```
[
    {
        Account_Number: 1,
        Account: 5,
        Category: "A",
        Balance: 500
    },
    {
        Account_Number: 1,
        Account: 5,
        Category: "A",
        Balance: 700
    },
    {
        Account_Number: 1,
        Account: 5,
        Category: "B",
        Balance: 300
    },
    {
        Account_Number: 1,
        Account: 5,
        Category: "C",
        Balance: 100
    },
    {
        Account_Number: 2,
        Account: 10,
        Category: "B",
        Balance: 300
    },
    {
        Account_Number: 2,
        Account: 10,
        Category: "B",
        Balance: 800
    }
]
```

Data Output

````
[
    {
        Account_Number: 1,
        Account: 5,
        CategoryA_Balance: 1200,
        CategoryB_Balance: 300,
        CategoryC_Balance: 100
    }
    {
        Account_Number: 2,
        Account: 10,
        CategoryA_Balance: 0,
        CategoryB_Balance: 1100,
        CategoryC_Balance: 0
    }
]```
````

Comment: is it mandatory to give fields that have value 0 in output?

Answer (score 1):

I assume Categories are dynamic. If not, you can replace the Categories variable with a static array.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var byAcctNbr = payload groupBy ($.Account_Number)
var categories = payload..Category distinctBy $
---
keysOf(byAcctNbr) map ((acctNbr) -> 
    do {
        var item = byAcctNbr[acctNbr] 
        var outItem = (item[0] default {}) - "Balance" - "Category"

        var balances = categories reduce ((category, acc={}) ->
            do {
                var accounts = item filter ($.Category == category)
                ---            
                acc ++ (
                        ("Category" ++ category ++ "_Balance"): if (isEmpty(accounts)) 0 
                                                                else sum (accounts.Balance)
                    )

        })
        ---
        outItem ++ balances
    }
)
```

Comment: Why are there dashes in the 4th from last line?

Comment: `-` operator removes the given key/value from the object (the output doesn't contain the Balance and Category)

Answer (score 0):

A Similar solution to sudhish. Breaking down the solution for better understanding

`distinctBy` Since `..` will give you all the categories present in the input. DistinctBy will remove duplicates and you will have [A,B,C]

`groupBy` to group based over details of each account number

`(item[0] - "Balance" - "Category")` Since we require AccountNumber and Account only once so used item[0] and "-" to eliminate Balance and Category since we need to perform some conditional based logic further

`pluck` to convert the object with account number as key to array

`map` iterates over the details of each account number

`map` over the categories will yield you [A,B,C] for both the account numbers

`filter` to check if the Category present in the top level map matches the categories present in the variable. if (true) then sum(Balance) else 0

`sum` to add based on the categories matched using filter

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var categories = payload..Category distinctBy $
--- 
payload groupBy $.Account_Number pluck $ map(item,index)->{
    (item[0] - "Balance" - "Category"),
    (categories map (cat)->{
        ("Category" ++ cat ++ "_Balance"):
            if (isEmpty(item filter ($.Category == cat)))
                 0
            else
               sum((item filter ($.Category == cat)).Balance)
    })
}
```